# Bus error (core dumped) while starting a NextJs project

Tags: npm, error-handling, next.js, runtime-error, project

I just finished creating a NextJs project and i ran `npm run dev` to start the project; but instead the terminal displays [image]
I'm currently not sure what is causing this. Please i need help

Comment: This is usually caused because of different versions of node.js in your system if you use nvm a lot.

Answer (score 2):

try and delete the project node modules and the lock file and redo npm install

Comment: I tried this, but it keeps repeating the same error.

Comment: @CletusKingdom, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

try to delete "_next" and "node_modules" folder with the package-lock.json file. then try npm install and npm run dev.

This worked for me